# datepicker doesn't show in asp.net using javascript, jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datepicker

I'm having a problem sliding Up and down the jquery datepicker on a click of a linked button. When the button is clicked, the text of the button is changed and depending on the text of the button datepicker is shown or hidden. Nothing is happening, only the name of the link button is changed quickly and changed back right away.

And the other question: if on document.ready I don't hide datepicker, it shows and disappears when some other trigger on the page is clicked. Why does it happen?
Here is what I have now:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $($('#datepicker').datepicker({
        minDate: new Date('04/26/1985'),
        maxDate: "-1Y",
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
    })).hide();
});

function clicked() {
    if ($('#<%=link_btn.ClientID%>').text() == "Later dates") {
            $('#<%=link_btn.ClientID%>').text("Older dates");
            $('#datepicker').slideUp();
            return false;
        }
        if ($('#<%=link_btn.ClientID%>').text() == "Older dates") {
            $('#<%=link_btn.ClientID%>').text("Later dates");
            $('#datepicker').slideDown();
            return false;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hiding the datepicker in this way will always hide the datepicker. I would do in this way:

In the markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $($('#datepicker').datepicker({
                minDate: new Date('04/26/1985'),
                maxDate: "-1Y",
                dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
            }))
        });
        function ToggleDate(myvalue) {
            if (myvalue == "Later dates") {
                $('#datepicker').show().slideUp();
            }
            else {
                $('#datepicker').slideDown();
            }

        };

    </script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <input id="datepicker" type="text" />
            <asp:LinkButton ID="link_btn" runat="server" OnClick="link_btn_Click">Later dates</asp:LinkButton>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And in the code:

```
protected void link_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string myScript = "ToggleDate('" + link_btn.Text + "');";
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "RegisterStartupScript", myScript, true);
    link_btn.Text = link_btn.Text == "Later dates" ? "Older dates" : "Later dates";
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. The datepicker doesn't show. It looks like the ToggleDate(myvalue)  is not being called, I included an alert msg in there, it doesn't show up.

Comment: That is strange, because the example is working fine for me. Did you check the markup in any tools like firebug? Did the jquery plugins included in your rendered page?

Comment: Thanks for checking. They are included in my master page. In code behind I changed 2nd line Page.ClientScript to  ScriptManager and ToggleDate(myvalue) is being called now. I forgot to mention that I need the datepicker as a div, so on the click of the link btn that div would show/hide. And initially it has to be hidden until the link btn is clicked. This is the div: <div id="datepicker" style="display:none;float:right">Date</div>. I've also tried changing visibility. On the click of the button it only shows/hides the word 'Date' and not the calendar. How can I fix that?

Comment: I have tested with the div also. I can see the calendar on the right side and working as expected. However, I don't have the masterpage you used.

Comment: I think I fixed it. I create the datepicker in the Toggle date function now, not in document.ready. Document.ready only executes once, and when some other control is triggered, the page is not loaded again, that's why I lose the datepicker. Thanks for helping!